# Gracefully handle invalid file uploads in Spring REST service

Tags: java, spring, rest, jersey, multipartform-data

I hit a roadblock trying to validate requests to a REST endpoint for uploading files. The upload works fine, as long as the request is correct, and now I'd like to include checks for whether the required fields are there and whether the data they contain are what I'm expecting.

I'm using Spring Boot 1.2.5 with `jersey-media-multipart` 2.1.4.

Here's the service:

```java
@Service
@Path("/attachments")
public class AttachmentsController {

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response upload(@FormDataParam("attachment") InputStream attachmentInputStream,
                           @FormDataParam("attachment") FormDataContentDisposition attachmentFileDetail) {

        if (null == attachmentInputStream
                || null == attachmentFileDetail
                || null == attachmentFileDetail.getFileName()) {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
        }

        // receiving, storing file, returning 201 Created responses etc.
    }

}
```

Now, when I test different scenarios:

1. Calling the endpoint with `multipart/form-data`, containing the file in the `attachment` field works correctly.
2. Calling without `multipart/form-data`, with the `attachment` field containing some text or without it, correctly enters the `if()` checking for `null` values, but the HTTP response becomes `404 Not Found` instead of the `400 Bad Request` I coded.
3. Calling without any fields (an empty request), regardless of whether it's `multipart/form-data`, triggers a `NullPointerException` pasted below, and returns a `404 Not Found` response.

Here's the `NullPointerException`:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [jerseyServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.FormDataParamValueFactoryProvider$FormDataParamValueFactory.provide(FormDataParamValueFactoryProvider.java:205)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.getParameterValues(ParameterValueHelper.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$AbstractMethodParamInvoker.getParamValues(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:121)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:152)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104)
    ...
```

Any ideas how to:

1. return the correct response 400 in case (2), and
2. gracefully handle case (3), avoiding the exception and returning code 400?

Comment: Why not configure error pages for these response codes and put them in web.xml??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end we found a solution for scenario 2 and a workaround for 3.

### Scenario 2

The `404 Not Found` responses we were getting were due to Jersey trying to display an error page, which didn't exist in the service. That default behavior can be turned off, in favor of simply returning the desired error code together with the coded response, by providing the following configuration:

```
@Component
public class WebServiceConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public WebServiceConfig() {
        property(ServerProperties.RESPONSE_SET_STATUS_OVER_SEND_ERROR, "true");
    }
}
```

### Scenario 3

This we worked around by adding a second service method for `POST` requests (named `uploadBodyMissing` below), expecting no parameters. So when there's a no-parameter `POST` coming in, this one would be invoked and return a `400 Bad Request` response:

```
@Service
@Path("/attachments")
public class AttachmentsController {

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response uploadBodyMissing() {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response upload(@FormDataParam("attachment") InputStream attachmentInputStream,
                           @FormDataParam("attachment") FormDataContentDisposition attachmentFileDetail) {

        if (null == attachmentInputStream
                || null == attachmentFileDetail
                || null == attachmentFileDetail.getFileName()) {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
        }

        // receiving, storing file, returning 201 Created responses etc.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding scenario 3:

Perhaps you could configure NullPointerException to result in a 400?

```
@ControllerAdvice
class GlobalControllerExceptionHandler {
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ExceptionHandler(NullPointerException .class)
    public void handleNull() {
        // Nothing to do
    }
}
```

Comment: `NullPointerException` is too generic to do so. There are many possible reasons for a `NullPointerException`, including originating in our own code, and in any case these are undesired and shouldn't occur under normal circumstances. Hence the appropriate response for such would be `500 Server Error` and we---the maintainers---would like to know about them as soon as possible.